# How to negotiate for higher salary

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I got a call from recruiter today to offer me 44,000 for a Financial analyst position. I asked for $48,000 and above in the interview. Told her to up it. She called back that the hiring manager said she cant go above 44,000. I would like to work at the company and wish they can truly increase the salary. How can i figure out whether  to accept or  try to re - negotiate or wait and hope they change their mind. They told me at the interview the highest range is 60,000

Comment: Either take the 44 or tell them you will walk away if they don't give you $X.

Comment: Hey Bernice. Currently, this question is off-topic, as it is asking us to make a choice for you... please read [how to ask](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and try to rephrase your post so it can be ontopic.

Comment: "How to negotiate" is a large enough topic that many books have been written about it. You are not going to be told the secrets in a three-paragraph answer here. Also neither you nor we know whether they might be prepared to pay $48,000 for you. There is no "These are not the droids you are looking for" trick you can do to change their mind.

Comment: You already have your answer. You asked for what you want in a salary, they told you they can't give it to you. Only you can decide if you would rather work for your desired salary, or work for this company. No one here can help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

Only you can determine what your acceptable salary is.  Do you believe you'd be happy making that much at that company?   Or do you believe you'd be better off waiting and hoping to get more at a different company?  Benefits also play into it.   Get information on the health insurance offered, if any, along with vacation time.   If you get 2 weeks of vacation and good insurance, that's easily worth $48 k without benefits in a different company.